# ¿Cómo forzar el sistema virtual Android o la máquina que ejecuta aplicaciones?

Tags: android

Quiero saber si es posible forzar al sistema la máquina virtual con la que las aplicaciones se ejecutan en android para ejecutar una aplicación en otra dirección que no ha sido instalada en el dispositivo que se almacena en mi aplicación como un recurso. Ya lo he instalado en un dispositivo para copiar todos los archivos que creo que son esenciales como el archivo apk, el .dex, el caché y sus datos en mi aplicación como un recurso, pero ahora quiero saber cómo ejecutarlo. Gracias.

Comment: ejecutar una aplicación en otra dirección que no ha sido instalada en el dispositivo que se almacena en mi aplicación como un recurso.  ¿Eso qué quiere decir?

Comment: Si eso mismo, perdón por  no responderte ante es que acabo de llegar, gracias.